# Generate plot coordinates for TikZ draw command

Tags: plotting

Is there some clever way to generate a TikZ plot sequence of draw coordinates in Mathematica? The following commands works fairly well

```
y[x_] := Log[2, (2 x - 200)/(x - 200)]
Table[{i, y[i]}, {i, 201, 2000, 10}] // N
```

but results in the output

```
{{201., 7.65821}, {211., 4.33498},...
```

I can post-process it in a text editor but it would better if it could be output in Mathematica as

```
(201., 7.65821)--
(211., 4.33498)--
(221., 3.52655)--
(231., 3.07923)--
(241., 2.78200)--
...
```

or something similar, to be easily used with the TikZ draw-command. I could loop through the list and 'format';

```
Clear[i, y];
y[x_] := Log[2, (2 x - 200)/(x - 200)];
coordinates = Table[{i, y[i]}, {i, 201, 2000, 10}] // N;
tikzlist = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[coordinates], i++,
 x = coordinates[[i]][[1]];
 y = coordinates[[i]][[2]];
 tikzlist = 
  tikzlist <> "(" <> ToString[x] <> "," <> ToString[y] <> ")--";
 ]
tikzlist = StringTake[tikzlist, StringLength[tikzlist] - 2] <> ";"
```

but perhaps there is some shorter one-line command that does the job better and more efficiently. TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TextString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextString.html) with its [`ListFormat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListFormat.html) option to directly format the list as needed, without any postprocessing:

```
TextString[
 TextString[#, ListFormat -> {"(", ", ", ")"}] & /@ tab1,
 ListFormat -> {"", "--\n", ""}
 ]
(* 
 (201., 7.65821)--
 (211., 4.33498)--
 (221., 3.52655)--
 (231., 3.07923)--
 (241., 2.782)--
 …
*)
```

Comment: That's even better !